# Can Oracle schema used size can be greater than tablespace used size?

Tags: oracle

In Oracle schema used size can be greater than tablespace used size ? If yes how its possible as schema is associated with tablespace ?

Comment: I highly recommend that you read the documentation on [Logical Storage Structures](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm)

Answer (score 1):

A schema is not "associated" with a tablespace.

A user (=schema) can have a *default* tablespace, but that does not necessarily mean that all tables that user owns are stored in that default tablespace. If the user has the privileges, tables can be created in other tablespaces as well.

Comment: A small addition to this answer: As well as a single schema being able to store segments across multiple tablespaces, a tablespace can house segments for objects from multiple schemas. A schema can be allowed to use only a set amount of space within a tablespace, or it can be unlimited.

Comment: So that means there is no similarity  schema used space and tablespace used space.  I basically would like to know can we compare the used space of space and tablespace in any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @a_horse_with_no_name  mentioned, you need to undrstand few basics of orale as well.

**Oracle Tablespace** -

- This is a logical structure, meaning that a tablespace is not a
  physical object
- A tablespace is made of 1 or more physical structures called
  datafiles. A datafile is a physical file on disk, just like any other file which sits on a hard disk but in an Oracle format. The datafile is created as part of a tablespace, and only one tablespace
- Each tablespace can have different characteristics, such as extent
  size and how the extents are managed
- They are used to group segments into logical
  groups. For example, you may have accounting data in one tablespace
  and reporting data in another.

**The Oracle Schema or User**

- Oracle Schema and user are synonymous and the terms are usually used
  interchangeably
- There can be thousands of users within one database
- The schema owns segments and objects (tables, indexes,views,
  constraints, etc) and each segment/object can belong to only one
  schema

Comment: Hmm "The schema owns segments (tables, indexes, etc) and objects..." does not ring quite true - tables and indexes are objects for a start. In fact, if you take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm#CNCPT004) you can see that `A single data segment in a database stores the data for one user object.`.

Comment: So i too mentioned the same. Isnt it..!!! If not then am sorry i couldnot understand what you wanted to point out. Or you mean to say a schema doesnot hold any segment its the other way

Comment: It's more Schemas own objects and objects can have segments. Your point reads as if tables and indexes are segments and not objects; it's a tad confusing.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Edited it.

Comment: thanks for the detailed suggestion, my question only here to can we relate Schema size with tablespace size or not .

Comment: Seems you didnot understood whats mentioned below. A schema takes space of a tablespace so anyways they are releated. What else you are looking for.